# How do I track the python badge?

Tags: support

In my profile, I would like to track the Python badge as I track other badges like, e.g.,  "Copy Editor" (just an example), but when I look for that tag I cannot find it.

Where or how can I track it?

Comment: Yay! The dupe worked